# How do you query the category id or name in Opencart 1.5.5.1 Joomla 3.3.0

Tags: joomla, opencart

So I am modifying a module and I've successfully queried the product ID.  So if I am browsing products and go into the product details page, I can see my product ID using

```
JRequest::getInt('product_id');
```

but for some reason I cannot get the category ID.  I've tried.

```
JRequest::getInt('category_id');
```

and it always comes out to zero no matter what category I go to.  Anyone else experience this?  I could get it from the nonSEF url but there's gotta be another way.  My goal is to basically query the category ID when I am browsing that category or if I am in the product details of a product.

Comment: Don't use JRequest, it's be deprecated since 1.6 and will disappear soon. Use [JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) instead.

Comment: AFAIK `Joomla!` has it's own e-commerce extension(s) - why using it with OpenCart (that is a standalone e-commerce solution with own CMS)? Are you using some Joomla! or OpenCart extension to make the two work together or you just building that? From the question I have no idea about what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you're using some OpenCart component for Joomla. In this case, you have to look into controller and model files for OpenCart. It's not THAT easy to get certain values sometimes, because these are 2 different engines.

In short, you may have to use VQMod for OpenCart, add category_id to data array and only then JRequest it. Solely depends on task.

Comment: I'm actually using Mijosef and modifying /administrator/components/com_mijosef/library/metadata.php so I'm trying to add what I can there.  Again I can get the product ID but not cat ID :P

Comment: Are you sure category ID is passed in the request? If yes, then it's probably stripped by router. In this case you won't be able to get it bu JRequest.